KQL: Render Timechart with API and response codes
I have a KQL query as follows.
cluster('Cluster1').database('DBName').TableName
| union cluster('Cluster2').database('DBName').TableName
| where TIMESTAMP > ago(1h)
   | extend API = <API Condition>
| project TIMESTAMP, request_uri, responsecode, CorrelationTag, tenantId, API
| order by todatetime(TIMESTAMP) desc
| summarize count() by API, responsecode, bin(TIMESTAMP, 5m)
| render timechart

THis produces a timechart as

API:APIName:Count
But I want to get the chart like within a given API what are the responsecodes like a 500, 200 etc..colorcoded.
How would I achieve that?

Do you have any source data you can include in your question for us to help with?

More data may be needed to understand what you want to see. But just from seeing your query, it will be difficult to render a timechart from 4 columns (API, responsecode, bin(TIMESTAMP, 5m), count_). Maybe you can try to concatenate the API and the response code and count from there:
cluster('Cluster1').database('DBName').TableName
| union cluster('Cluster2').database('DBName').TableName
| where TIMESTAMP > ago(1h)
| extend API = <API Condition>
| extend API_responsecode = strcat(API, " - ", responsecode)
| summarize count() by time_bin=bin(TIMESTAMP, 5m), API_responsecode
| sort by time_bin asc
| render columnchart// timechart defaults to line chart which will be hard to visualize. 

references:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/visualization-columnchart?pivots=azuredataexplorer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/strcat-function
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/visualization-timechart?pivots=azuredataexplorer
